# Facebook Ads api - ad stats for video post - watched 100%

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

When I use the following command I get the ad details

```
1234/stats
```

For a specific ad for a video post I can get the video_play and video_view.
But, is there a way to know how many people watch 100% of the video using the Ads API?

I saw it on the ads manager, but I can't find a way to query this data with the Ads API.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Ad Report Stats api endpoint, under the “Actions” Data Column.

Here’s an example: `act_XXXX/reportstats?actions_group_by=['action_type']&date_preset=last_7_days&filters=[{'field':'campaign_id','type':'in','value':[]}]&data_columns=['campaign_name','video_p50_watched_actions']&access_token=ZZZ`

Chris

Comment: Thanks! Is there a place where I can find all available actions for the action_type column?